# Hide element after transform on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a video player transforming to display at the bottom of the video on hover.

How can I hide the div again after 3 seconds of the video time, even when hovering over the video?

```css
.video-block {
  display: flex;
}

.box-btns {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(54, 91, 160, 0.56);
  z-index: 2;
  flex: 1;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.9s;
}

.video-block:hover {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-block">
  <video id="main-video" src="../css/abc.mp4"></video>
  <div class="media-box">
    <div class="box-btns">
      <button onclick="playVideo()" class="play-btn">
        <i class="ion-play"></i>
      </button>
      <button onclick="pauseVideo()" class="pause-btn">
        <i class="ion-pause"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### I will show you some example so I think you can get some **Idea** of that

---

***I used JQuery!***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

***This part show video on the webpage***

```
<video width=640 muted src="CotswoldSequence1.mov" id="playvid" ontimeupdate="getvidtime(this)"></video>
```

***I use this part to get the current time of the video***

```
ontimeupdate="getvidtime(this)"
```

***This one show you current time of the video during the playing***

```
    function getvidtime(event) {

        getCurrentTime = Math.trunc(event.currentTime);        

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getCurrentTime;
    }
```

***This one is show the time when you move the mouse over the video***

```
$('#myvid').mouseenter(function(){
    $( ".demox" ).text(getCurrentTime);
});
```

***This section when you move mouse on the video button will be show otherwise it will be hide***

```
    $('#myvid').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#playbtn').show();
    });
    $('#myvid').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#playbtn').hide();
    });
```

***In this section when click the button if ID equel to button ID video will be play and after 3sec button hide as well as when you move mouse out of the the video and then move mouse on the video you can see the which second mouse move on the video " $( ".demox" ).text(getCurrentTime);" and after 3sec buttton hide***

```
    $('#playbtn').click(function(){

        if(this.id == 'playbtn'){
            $('#playvid')[0].play();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#playbtn').fadeOut();
                }, 3000);

             $('#myvid').mouseenter(function(){
               $( ".demox" ).text(getCurrentTime);
                   setTimeout(() => {
                      $('#playbtn').hide(); 
                   }, 3000);
                });
           }
    });
```

---

### Here is the full code

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class = container style="max-width: 640px;" id="myvid">

        <video width=640 muted src="CotswoldSequence1.mov" id="playvid" ontimeupdate="getvidtime(this)"></video>
    <div>
        <button class=controls id="playbtn" style="position: fixed; top: 332px; left: 12px;">Play/pause</button> 
    </div>
        <p>Playback position: <span id="demo"></span></p>

        Mouseenter position: <p class="demox"></p>
</div>

    <script>

    var getCurrentTime;

    function getvidtime(event) {

        getCurrentTime = Math.trunc(event.currentTime);        

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getCurrentTime;
    }

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#myvid').mouseenter(function(){
                $('#playbtn').show();
            });
            $('#myvid').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#playbtn').hide();
            });

            $('#playbtn').click(function(){

                if(this.id == 'playbtn'){
                    $('#playvid')[0].play();
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            $('#playbtn').fadeOut();
                        }, 3000);

                    $('#myvid').mouseenter(function(){
                        $( ".demox" ).text(getCurrentTime);
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                $('#playbtn').hide(); 
                            }, 3000);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

---

- I used **settimeout** because it give same time for the video time
- you can use your own video to **src="CotswoldSequence1.mov"** here
- copy this code and past to your editor and run see whats happen!
- I think you can get some idea!

Answer (score 0):

If I assume well you want to hide the controls after certain seconds of moving the mouse over rather than after playing. Otherwise you would not be able to pause the video.

I am going to use JavaScript for this. First of all added the `mousemove` event to add and remove the class responsable of showing the button controls instead of using CSS. I add the `box-btns--visible` class to the video controls whenever there is a mouse movement over the video. Then I create a 3 seconds timer to remove the `box-btns--visible` class from the controls, but if I move the mouse before the timer ends I reset the timer. I added the play and pause events and an open source video for you to play around. You can visit this documentation links for better understanding.

[HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play)
[Mouse over event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) *It is not the same event but it has a good example related to your use case*

```js
const playButton = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
const pauseButton = document.querySelector('.pause-btn');
const video = document.getElementById('main-video');
const controls = document.querySelector('.box-btns');

let timer;

function hideControls() {
  timer = setTimeout(() => controls.classList.remove('box-btns--visible'), 3000);
}

function preventHideControls() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
} 

video.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  controls.classList.add('box-btns--visible');  
  preventHideControls();
  hideControls();
});

playButton.addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
  try {
    await video.play();
    playButton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    pauseButton.removeAttribute('disabled');

  } catch (err) {
    playButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});

pauseButton.addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
  try {
    await video.pause();
    pauseButton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    playButton.removeAttribute('disabled');

  } catch (err) {
    pauseButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.video-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-btns {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(54, 91, 160, 0.56);
  z-index: 2;
  flex: 1;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

.box-btns--visible {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.playing {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-block">
  <video id="main-video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"></video>
  <div class="media-box">
    <div class="box-btns">
      <button class="play-btn">
        Play
      </button>
      <button class="pause-btn" disabled>
        Pause
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was really helpful thank you so much, I'll replace my code now :D 
Is there a way to keep the `box-btns` if still hover?

Comment: You can use the `mouseenter` event to show the controls and hide theme until the mouse is out with the `mouseleave` event!
This means you are only listening to when the mouse entered and when it left, instead of listening to all mouse movement over the video.